# Loan calculator compound interest java

Tags: java

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText());
double r = Double.parseDouble(rate.getText())/100;
double y = Double.parseDouble(years.getText());
double m=y*12;
double simple =a+(a*r*y);
double compound = a * Math.pow(1+ r, m);
String d = String.format("%.2f", simple);
String d1 = String.format("%.2f", simple/12);
String d2 = String.format("%.2f", compound);
int x=1;

while(x<=m && type.getSelectedItem().equals("Simple")) {
     monthly1.append(String.valueOf(x+(". ")+d1+("\n"))); 
     x++;
     total1.setText(String.valueOf(d));
}

if (type.getSelectedItem().equals("Compound")){
    for (int month=1;month<=m;month++){
       monthly2.append(String.valueOf(month+(". ")+d2+"\n"));
       total2.setText(String.valueOf(d2));
     } 
}
```

Simple interest works fine but compound monthly doesn't. I tried

> amount:1000 rate:5 years 3.

And got

```
1. 5791.82
2. 5791.82
3. 5791.82

up to 60.
```

And I want it to show how much I have to pay monthly.

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: You *must* use a currency type when dealing with actual money payments. A `double` is too imprecise. This is not your immediate problem by the way.

Comment: When I use formula for year a * Math.pow(1+ r, y); it generates total value right but month still doesn't work and I got no idea how to fix it.

Comment: how are you calculating monthly interest?

Answer (score 1):

You only seem to calculate `compound` once, at the very beginning of your code. I'd create a method `calculateCompoundInterest(int month)` and then call this from within your loop like so:

```
for (int month=1; month <= m; month++) {
    String monthlyAmount = String.format("%.2f", calculateCompoundInterest(month));
    monthly2.append(String.valueOf(month+(". ")+monthlyAmount+"\n"));
    total2.setText(String.valueOf(d2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating monthly interest incorrectly.

formula `a* Math.pow(1+r,y)` needs to be applied like `a* Math.pow(1+r/12,y*12)` if compounded monthly. you need to convert your rate as well to use in the formula.

[Please see this](https://qrc.depaul.edu/StudyGuide2009/Notes/Savings%20Accounts/Compound%20Interest.htm) for more explanation of formula.

Here is the code to help you started:

```
for (int month=1;month<=m;month++){
   d2 = String.format("%.2f",a * Math.pow(1+ r/12, month));
   monthly2.append(String.valueOf(month+(". ")+d2+"\n"));
   total2.setText(String.valueOf(d2));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for formula but whatever I do still getting bunch of identical lines. I can't make that loop work :(

Comment: @user3667875 That's because you're only calculating the total once, for the complete number of months, at the beginning of your code. As mentioned, you want to calculate it for _each_ number of months from `1` up to `m * 12`

Comment: I know but I don't know how just can't figure. Dumb(I guess?)

Comment: The amended answer above won't work either. You need to use `a * Math.pow(1 + r/12, month)`, as `month` is the loop variable - `m` is just the same constant used before. I've created a pending edit to this answer to fix this.

Comment: I know just not enough reputation yet.